# SQLCMD - Copy data from one table to other

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition. I am trying to copy data from `master.Lic` table to `mydb.Lic` table. Following is the query.

```
insert into mydb.dbo.Lic
("key",value)
select "key",value from master.dbo.Lic
```

If I execute above query from the Visual Studio's SQL query prompt it works!!

However, when I am trying the same query using `SQLCMD` I am facing following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Server NB\SQLEXPRESS, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'value'.
```

Need suggestion on how this can be done using SQLCMD on the user machine I can use only SQLCMD.

**EDIT:**

Command to connect SQLCMD

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sqlcmd -S .\sqlexpress
1> use mydb
2> go
Changed database context to 'mydb'.
```

Comment: Can you provide how you're calling `sqlcmd` ?

Comment: Try putting the word value in brackets [value].   Value is a reserved word in SQL

Comment: putting it into brackets worked!! :)
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct Query:

```
insert into dbo.SoftwareLicence
([key],[value])
select [key],[value] from master.dbo.SoftwareLicence
```